# dealing with empty elements in ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am returning some data from a web service to a rails page. However sometimes an element is present, sometimes it's not. This seems like it would deal with the case when the `videos` element is not present, but it throws an error:

```
<% if @data['videos'].present? && !@data['videos'].empty? %>
    <div class="tab-pane map" id="video"></div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the error:

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I properly ignore the element if it is not present?

Comment: What is the class of the `videos` object?

Comment: What about `@data['videos'].try(:empty?)` ?

Comment: Are you certain that's where the error is coming from? Because `present?` will return false for nil, so you'd never get to the `empty?` check. (Incidentally, it's pointless to check for `empty?` after checking for `blank?` or `present?`, because `blank?` already checks for that condition if the object can be empty.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.present?` instead of `.empty?`

```
1.9.3p489 :003 > ''.present?
 => false 
1.9.3p489 :004 > ''.empty?
 => true 
1.9.3p489 :005 > nil.present?
 => false 
1.9.3p489 :006 > nil.empty?
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

---

**In your case:**

```
<% if @data['videos'].present? %>
    <div class="tab-pane map" id="video"></div>
<% end %>
```

---

**Additionnal note:**

[`.blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) is the exact opposite of [`.present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F):

```
class Object

  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
  end

  def present?
    !blank?
  end
```

---

**Another note:**

The method [`.presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) is quite usefull (it returns the object if it responds `true` to `.present?`):

```
1.9.3p489 :008 > params = { name: '' }
 => {:name=>""} 
1.9.3p489 :009 > user_name = params[:username].presence || 'DefaultName'
 => "DefaultName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove following part from the condition used in code

```
&& !@data['videos'].empty?
```